# Issues while implementing custom sort/ data fetching logic for Amazon DynamoDb table

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I'm having a s3 bucket which is hookedup to the DynamoDb table named "assetbucket-index". Which i'm thinking to use DynamoDb as indexing for searching files. Can you guys give me an idea to solve the following  requirement. I need to implement using Amazon JavaScript sdk.

**What i need?**

Search data by asset name and get result format as most matched first, partial matched follows next and limiting to 1000 records per page and then using lazy loading.

Eg. On searching assetName "Tom Cruise" need to get as follows

1. Exact match results first "Tom Cruise" - (matched 900 records)
2. Then search for Tom* - (matched 900 records)
3. Then search for Cruise* - (matched 1100 records)

So, if we have 2900 records matched for three queries, then will form 3 pages and now Page 1 need to have 900("Tom Cruise")+100(Tom*) records, Page2 need to have 800("Tom*")+200(Cruise*) records and Page3 need to have 900 records.

**Table Structure: ("assetbucket-index")**

```
asset-id -> PrimaryKey
asset-created-date -> Sort Key
assetname
key
assetextension
assetmimetype
assetpublishedstart
..... fields added dynamically.

Global Secondary Index:
assetname -> hash key
```

**What i thought to implement?**

1. assetname="Tom Cruise" - (This can be done)
2. contains(assetname,"Tom") AND assetname<>"Tom Cruise"
3. contains(assetname,"Cruise") AND assetname<>"Tom Cruise"

> *Reg. 2&3:* Getting error [Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key
>   attributes: Primary key attribute: assetname]

Currently i'm using the following JavaScript code.

```
this.searchByAssetName = function(assetName, indexName, callbackFn){
        if(dynDbConn !== false && typeof assetName!="undefined" && assetName != ""){
            var params = {
                TableName: options.table,
                KeyConditionExpression: '#asset_name = :asset_name_val',
                'ExpressionAttributeNames':{
                    '#asset_name':"assetname"
                },
                'ExpressionAttributeValues':{
                    ':asset_name_val':{'S':assetName}
                }
            };

            if(typeof indexName!="undefined" && indexName!=""){
                params.IndexName = indexName;
            }

            dynDbConn.query(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    if(typeof err.message !="undefined"){
                        this.passErrorMessage(err.message);
                    }
                    if(typeof callbackFn == "function"){
                        callbackFn(err, data, params);
                    }
                } else {
                    if(typeof callbackFn == "function"){
                        callbackFn(err, data, params);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
```